# What regulations apply to bicycles in New York City, USA

Tags: safety

I have heard of many incidents where cyclists got ticketed for something small, but I can't find the actual rules for cyclists online anywhere. Where are they?

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha, some how I got it lol. It was a round trip, but hope help those ppl aware of this

http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/downloads/pdf/bicyclerules_english.pdf